# Creating archetype using jcodemodel

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I am trying to create a maven archetype in which I am trying to autogenerate the code in a java class. I have came across jcodemodel to generate java class. Anyone kindly guide me hoe to do it and where do i need to use jcodemodel in archetype inorder to generate a class file in specific folder with a given name from user?

The archetype gets the input such as servicename, artifactid from user while generating code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven archetypes can use velocity templates to create code, one simple example beeing to create to correct package definitions. The [JBoss Wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenArchetypeCreationGuidelines) contains a simple example of a template containing conditional logic.

If you already have a generator using codemodel, the [generate goal of the archetype plugin](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html) contains a `goals` parameter the execute additional plugins after creation. You could let the archetype create only the directory structure, wrap your generator into a maven plugin and then execute on the newly created project.